# SSIS: Extract the target table of an OLE DB Destination object

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to use the SQL Server SSIS API libraries to determine extac information from all of our packages including the destination tables that are being populated in a OLE DB Destination object.

I see that one of the objects in the Pipeline (Data Flow Task) is an OLE DB Destination (Class ID 5A0B62E8-D91D-49F5-94A5-7BE58DE508F0) but for the life of me I can't figure out what interface to cast the loop variable "componentMetadata" to to get at the name of the target table.

```
 foreach (IDTSComponentMetaData100 componentMetadata in pipeline.ComponentMetaDataCollection)
 {

 }
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Sum btch. I found it right after asking.

```
string targetTableName = componentMetadata.OutputCollection[0].Component.CustomPropertyCollection["OpenRowset"].Value.ToString();
```